# Content view binding not working

Tags: forms, xamarin

```
I have ContentView which need ViewModel binding
```

Test.xaml

```
<ContentView.Content>  
 <Frame x:Name="HelpBaseFrame" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="16" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <StackLayout>
                 <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="lstview" SeparatorColor="White">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell IsEnabled="False">
                                    <ScrollView x:Name="ScrollView" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0, 1, 0, 0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Label x:Name="LabelHeader" FontAttributes="Bold" Font="HiraginoSans-W6, 16" 
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                                                <Label.Text>
                                                    <Binding Path="HeaderData"></Binding>
                                                </Label.Text>
                                            </Label>
                                            <local:LineSpacingLabel x:Name="LabelHeaderDesceiption" LineSpacing="6"
                                                Font="HiraginoSans-W3, 16" FontAttributes="None" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                                                <Label.Text>
                                                    <Binding Path="DescriptionData"></Binding>
                                                </Label.Text>
                                            </local:LineSpacingLabel>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ScrollView>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>                  
            </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
</ContentView.Content>
```

BindingClass

```
public void SetData(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
         ............
        lstview.ItemsSource = HelpDataList;  // HelpDataList is observable collection of HElp Data        
    }
```

Model class :

```
public class HelpData : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string Header = string.Empty;
        private string Description = string.Empty;

        public string HeaderData
        {
            get { return Header; }
            set
            {
                Header = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HeaderData");
            }               
        }
        public string DescriptionData { get; set; }
    }
```

This view model for above view. 
 This binding is not working.
 Is anything  wrong?
 This view model for above view. 
 This binding is not working.
 Is anything  wrong?
 This view model for above view. 
 This binding is not working.
 Is anything  wrong?

Comment: Not clear to answer, put you complete code here

Comment: Kept all code ..

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to set `bindingContext` on the target control by using `x:Reference` markup extension.

   ```
   BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=ViewModelField}"
   ```

   Or

   ```
   BindingContext="{x:Reference ViewModelField}"
   ```
2. `Label.Text` should be binding with `string` not `viewModel`.

   ```
   Text="{Binding Path=Value}"
   ```

   Or

   ```
   Text="{Binding Value}"  ( “Path=” part of the markup extension can be omitted if the path is the first item in the Binding markup extension)
   ```

Refer to [Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#View-to-View_Bindings)

#### Update

`<Binding>`  is not a valid tag.

Modify the label :

```
<Label Text="{Binding Path = HeaderData}">
```

Comment: Text="{Binding Value}" its works fine . but it adds code analysis error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CA0001 CA0001 : Member 'get_Assembly' could not be found in type 'System.Type' in assembly ', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral Active"

Comment: `Value ` here means the `string property` in your viewModel. Could you attach the code with class ViewModelField

Comment: <Label Text="{Binding Path = HeaderData}">its works fine . but it adds code analysis error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CA0001 CA0001 : Member 'get_Assembly' could not be found in type 'System.Type' in assembly ', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral Active"  Which I dont want.

Comment: <Label.Text>
          <Binding Path="DescriptionData"></Binding>
   </Label.Text>   This is not adding any code analysis error, bu t not working with Content view, Above way is Ok with content page.

Comment: It is weird, try `<Label Text="{Binding  HeaderData}">`

Comment: <Label Text="{Binding HeaderData}"> This way also adding code analysis error.

Comment: How we can bind view cell data on code behind? Have you any idea?

Comment: @saritas refer to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance/#C